# What features are missing from Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ide

Microsoft has recently announced the release of Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition, which they claim is a full featured IDE.

Indeed, they mention features like add-on support (eg. ReSharper) that were major feature gaps in Express Edition.

They are less clear about what features Community Edition does not have. There is a [comparison of VS editions](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-products-vs.aspx#), but it does not appear to include Community Edition.

What features does Community Edition not have, that at least one other Visual Studio 2013 edition does?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Microsoft notes in the Community Edition FAQ:

> Visual Studio Community 2013 includes **all the great functionality of Visual Studio Professional 2013**, designed and optimized for individual developers, students, open source contributors, and small teams.

VS Professional *is* mentioned on the comparison. Compared to Ultimate, the following features are missing from Professional:

- Debugging

  - IntelliTrace in Production
  - IntelliTrace (Historical Debugging)
  - IntelliTrace Performance Indicators
  - .NET Memory Dump Analysis
  - Code Map Debugger Integration
  - Performance and Diagnostics Hub does not include Tier Interaction Profiling
- Testing Tools

  - Web Load & Performance Testing
  - Microsoft Fakes
  - Code Coverage
  - Coded UI Testing
  - Manual Testing
  - Exploratory testing
  - Test Case Management
  - Fast-forward for Manual Testing
- Integrated Development Environment

  - CodeLens
  - Code Clone
  - Blend does not include SketchFlow
- Architecture and Modeling

  - Architecture Explorer
  - Architecture and Layer Diagrams
  - Architecture validation
  - UML 2.0 Compliant Diagrams
  - Code dependency graphs and code maps are read only
- Team Foundation Server

  - Web-based Test Case Management
  - Agile Portfolio Management
  - Team Room
  - Work Item Charting is read-only
  - Request and Manage Feedback
  - Release Management
- Visual Studio Online services

  - Cloud-based Web Load and Performance Testing
  - Web-based Test Case Management
  - Agile Portfolio Management
  - Team Room
  - Work Item Charting is read only
  - Request and Manage Feedback
- Collaboration tools

  - PowerPoint Storyboarding
  - Code Review
  - Task Suspend/Resume
- Various subscriptions for Microsoft services and products which probably are not relevant for Community Edition.

It's probably safe to assume this is a good description of features missing from Community Edition.

Answer (score 3):

This is the updated feature comparison info page for Visual Studio 2015.

https://www.visualstudio.com/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs

It is not totally on par with the Professional Edition, but there is still huge amount of value there!

Comment: Thank you, that's quite helpful, and probably will become even more so as everyone switches to 2015. This question *is* about specifically 2013, though, so may be the 2015 one should be its own question/answer?

Comment: Probably yes, i just threw it in there since i found this question before finally landing on the 2015 page i was looking for. Cheers.